# How to perform XPath on individual elements in PHP using SimpleXML?

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml

I have the following example XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<database>
    <record>
        <id>1</id>
        <a>5</a>
    </record>
    <record>
        <id>5</id>
        <a>8</a>
    </record>
    <record>
        <id>7</id>
        <!--No a record!-->
    </record>
    <record>
        <id>6</id>
        <a>10</a>
    </record>
</database>
```

I want to iterate through each "record" element and fetch it's corresponding "a" element if it exists.

I attempted this using the following code:

```
  $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlStringDataFromFile);
  foreach ($xml->record as $record) {
      $id = $record->xpath("//id")[0];
      $a = $record->xpath("//a")[0];
      echo "{$id}: {$a}\n";
  }
```

However the xpath performed is on the entire document. not on the individual "record" element. Thus I got the following output:

```
1: 5
1: 5
1: 5
1: 5
```

I want the following output:

```
1: 5
5: 8
7: 
6: 10
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `//` at the beginning of the XPath expression it will search from the document root and you always end up with the same result. Since the `id` and `a` elements are directly under `record` simply use

```
  $id = $record->xpath("id")[0];
  $a = $record->xpath("a")[0];
```

If they would be at same level below `record` start the XPath expression with a `.` to search relative to the context node:

```
  $id = $record->xpath(".//id")[0];
  $a = $record->xpath(".//a")[0];
```